# (Python) How to pull random elements from a list according to user input?

Tags: python, user-input

I'm writing a program which will create 4 lists with words in them. A user is prompted to answer how many words they'd like to print from list A, how many from list B, how many from list C, D etc. and the program randomly chooses those words and prints them out.

I've got the shell out ready, the lists are made up, and the user input prompts are done, I can't figure out how to connect these two together. I can print out random values from a list using random.choice() but the amount that I specify. Not the number of words the user specifies.

The code is something like this:

```
def lists():
    animal = ["cat", "dog", "horse", "cow", "rabbit"]
    furnishings = ["couch", "table", "chair", "lamp", "bed"]
    vehicle = ["mazda", "toyota", "ford", "cadillac", "honda"]
    shade = ["red", "blue", "black", "green", "purple"]

def inputFunction():

    animals = input("how many animals would you like to print? ")
    furniture = input("how many furniture pieces would you like to print? ")
    cars = input("how many cars would like to use? ")
    colors = input("how many colors? ")

def main():
```

***please note this is not the entire code but an oversimplified version of it to illustrate what I mean ***

The output I want is something along the lines of:

how many animals would you like to print? 2
how many furniture pieces would you like to print? 3
how many cars would like to use? 1
how many colors?  5

cat horse table lamp bed toyota red blue black green purple.

Comment: From you description `random.choices` seems like a better choice than `random.choice`. The `choices` method has a parameter which specifies how many to choose. That parameter can be obtained from user input.

Comment: The code that you posted doesn't make sense. The variables such as `animals`  inside `lists` are local variables whose values will be lost when the call to `lists` returns. Doubtless this isn't your real code -- but why not post sample code that actually makes sense?

Answer (score 1):

Python has the built-in module `random` that contains a function known as `choice` which randomly selects an element from a list. Import it using the following.

```py
from random import choice
```

`x` is that list containing the words.
`n` is how much you want the new list elements be.
`acc` is an accumulator.
How this function works is that we select a random element from the list, add it to the accumulator and re-call the function with decrement of `n` till it reaches `0`, were we return the accumulator.

```py
cr_list = lambda x, n, acc: acc if n == 0 else cr_list(x, n-1, acc + [choice(x)])
```

Here's an example of the function.

```py
data_base = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
print(cr_list(data_base, 4, []))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define one variable that come from the user, let say "x", this variable take the value:

```
hmf=[] #this is the list that in each spaces the number of selection random words

for j in (0,4):
  x=int(input())
  hmf.append(x)
```

In that case you have:

```
# hmf[0] = numbers of words from the list A
# hmf[1] = numbers of words from the list B
# hmf[2] = numbers of words from the list C
# hmf[3] = numbers of words from the list D
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is the code you are looking for:

```
import random

animal = ["cat", "dog", "horse", "cow", "rabbit"]
furnishings = ["couch", "table", "chair", "lamp", "bed"]
vehicle = ["mazda", "toyota", "ford", "cadillac", "honda"]
shade = ["red", "blue", "black", "green", "purple"]


animals = int(input("how many animals would you like to print? "))
furniture = int(input("how many furniture pieces would you like to print? "))
cars = int(input("how many cars would like to use? "))
colors = int(input("how many colors? "))

print("Random animals list: ", random.choices(animal, k=animals))
print("Random furnishings list: ", random.choices(furnishings, k=furniture))
print("Random vehicle list: ", random.choices(vehicle, k=cars))
print("Random shade list: ", random.choices(shade, k=colors))
```

which outputs:

```
Random animals list:  ['cow', 'dog']
Random furnishings list:  ['couch', 'lamp']
Random vehicle list:  ['toyota', 'cadillac']
Random shade list:  ['purple', 'black']
```